# Laravel PHP: Container not floating left

Tags: php, css, laravel-4

I'm currently working on a homepage using the Laravel PHP Framework and I'm running into CSS issues.  I'm trying to accomplish a simple task of having two things in my '**header**' tag,

1) An image of a logo on the left 
2) A container to the right of the logo displaying a user's information

The logo is positioned fine on the left but when I try to position the container to the right of it, it is being positioned underneath the logo instead.  I know my CSS is good unless I'm overlooking something entirely but I have a feeling that the Larevel Blade Templating is having an effect in how '**div**' elements are being handled.

**CSS(style.css)**:

```
body {
background:linear-gradient(#3C5D79, #2E4253) no-repeat;
color:white;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.header_container {
width:960px;
}

.main_logo_container  {
  width:313px;
  margin:0 170px;
  position:relative;
}


.admin_container {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:600px;
  margin:5px 5px;
  position:relative;
}
```

@extends ('layouts.default')

**Admin View after user logs in (admin_index.blade.php):**

```
@section('content')

<header>
    <div class="header_container">
        <div class="main_logo_container">

        <img src="../images/logo.png" width="300" height="97" alt="Company Logo" />

        <div class="admin_container">   

        <b> You have reach the admin page!</b>  

        </div>


        </div>
    </div>     

</header>

@stop
```

**layouts.default.blade.php(Main Blade Template):**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

    <meta charset ="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" <?php echo asset('css/style.css')?>" type="text/css">

    <style>.flash { padding: 1em;  border: 1px dotted black; } </style>

</head> 

<body>

    @if (Session::get('flash_message'))

        <div class="flash">
            {{ Session::get('flash_message') }}
        </div>

    @endif      


    <div class="container">

        @yield('content')

    </div>


</body>



</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated since I'm trying to become more familiar with Laravel PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logo container was too small because according to your DOM it also carries your text which is 600px wide for a 313px wide container hence the split on two separate lines.

I suggest you change your `CSS` to fix this and also remove the `float: left` directive. The `display: inline-block` here will be more efficient.

Therefore you will get this following CSS:

```
body {
background:linear-gradient(#3C5D79, #2E4253) no-repeat;
color:white;
}

.header_container {
width:960px;
}

.main_logo_container  {
  width: 100%;
}

.main_logo_container img {
    display: inline-block;
}


.admin_container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position:relative;
  top: -40px;
}
```

And here is a demo to show you the working result:
**http://jsfiddle.net/w7wqaw9L/**

Comment: This is really good and I like your explanation.  Works fine for me now!  I originally thought it might've been a Blade Templating issue but it was CSS after all lol.  Thank you very much!